# If statement within a loop - google app scripts regarding dates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKCY0.png)I want to programmatically label certain cells "past" if the month is in the past by checking the first day of the month with a loop statement.  It only seems to be working of the first line, but not moving to the later lines

I expect all of the first cells in the right column of the boarder in the 4th rows to return "past" until oct 1st.  I'm just getting the result in the first cell and almost infinitely getting the "Running function findCurrentMonthTest..." message at the top of the screen.

```
function findpastMonthTest(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();


  var today = ss.getRange(3, 1).getValues();

  for(var i = 2; i < 16;i+3){
    var date =ss.getRange(3,i).getValue(); 
    if(today>date){
      ss.getRange(4, i).setValue("Past");
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: sorry I changed it to be more applicable to the question.  It actually says "running function findPastMonthTest" in this situation.  Thanks for the clarifying question.

Comment: `for(var i = 2; i < 16;i+3)` in this for loop, `i` never changes ... you want `i+=3`

Comment: This worked! Thanks

Comment: @Bravo - might I request you to post your comment as an answer :) ? Hoping that OP marks this answered then.